# Spring request Thread closing

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thread-safety

I'm using Spring Boot and every time, when I make request to my RestController, new Thread created. How can I close these threads explicitly? I mean, when something returned from my mapped method, Thread, in which it was executed, closes.

I know, that here is thread-pool in Tomcat, but I want do it all with my bare hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring the controllers has a default singleton scope. So there is only one instance of the controller. The number of threads is controlled by the number of instances of dispatcher servlet. You can see how to configure that number in the Spring MVC tutorial.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

And here how to manage thread safe

https://studiofreya.com/2012/02/06/spring-mvc-how-to-build-a-thread-safe-controller/

Comment: Thanks for the links, very usefull. But I still have a question, how to close Thread, created by the new request, manually.

Comment: The servlets container help you manage the threads. So you don't have to worry about that kind of things. I think if you want to manage the servlet threads by yourself you need to build your own servlet container.

Comment: Thank you. May bee it's better not to touch low-level parts of framework :D